# NextJS array mapping for POST request

Tags: javascript, mongoose, post, next.js

I am learning Next.js currently, and I have a question.

I have this data as a `req.body`:

```json
{
    "name": "Name Here",
    "phone": [
        {
            "phonetype": "Work",
            "phonenumber": "PhoneNumber1"
        },
        {
            "phonetype": "Home",
            "phonenumber": "PhoneNumber2"
        }
    ],
    "city": "CityHere"
}
```

And I am trying to create a new Customer in the database. Below is my POST:

```js
case 'POST':
    try{
        const customer = req.body;
        const newCustomer = new Customer({
            name: customer.name,
            //phone: HOW TO I HANDLE THIS ARRAY?
            city: customer.city,
        });

        const createdCustomer = await Customer.create(newCustomer);
                
        res.status(201).json({success: true, data: createdCustomer});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({success: false, data: "Error Creating Customer"});
    }
    break;
```

How do I go about submitting it to the database (using Mongoose)?

Schema below:

```js
const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    phone: {
        phonetype: {
            type: String,
        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    }
})
```